# pb12.6 - complex window hierarchy- bad runtime error, mistake or bug?

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy

Hi,

we're developing our product on pb 12.6 Build 4035 - Classic. Now we have following problem:

We have a complex window hierarchy, where each level has a special kind of functionality and becoming more and more complex. On the highest level is a visual userobject. This got the instance var to the window. If the user does any task in the userobject we send over the instance var the actions to the window. Delevoping -> Saving -> Running is all okay. **BUT** after the **deploy** the function to the window ends up in a bad runtime reference. This error occurs in running out of powerbuilder (only after deploy) and running the exe (standalone). After a new save of our userobject, it's working again.

Our window hierachie:

from lowest to highest level

- wo_window ( simple window, basic functions, like a msgbox )

- wo_uni (window has right system and more functions)

- wo_sheet (window can communicate with database)

- wo_tab (window has a tabpage )

- wo_tab_obj ( object window, special functions, objects are items or address, highest level of hierarchy )

- w_adr ( object window for adress )

on wo_tab_obj is our userobject.   => wo_tab_obj::open{ uo_blaettern_obj.event ue_set_ref( /*wo_tab_obj awo_tab_obj */ this ) }

->in the userobject the reference is stored in iwo_tab_obj

user starts action on the userobject and the code calls: iwo_tab_obj.get_obj().get_parameterart()

the function call get_obj() throws the exception bad runtime reference. get_obj() is declared at wo_tab_obj. So now we tried something and called function of lower hierarchy level. this is working (also after compiling, and running the exe).

the exception also appers at events, calling a event which is declared at wo_uni works.

So we think there's a bug inside the compiling process, or are we doing something wrong?

We won't recreate our window hierarchy, because it's perfect for our tasks, we need all of this levels.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it's a bug in the compile process.  The more likely scenario is a pointer problems in the compiled P-code...  Is there any chance you have a circular object reference somewhere in the hierarchy?

For example, somewhere in wo_tab_obj, you might have a reference to some userobject or NVO class, which itself has a declaration that references back to  wo_tab_obj.